# SQL Compare Two Rows from Same Table and make new column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the initial table

| num | did | lat1 | lon1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d1 | x1 | y1 |
| 2 | d1 | x2 | y2 |
| 3 | d2 | x3 | y3 |
| 4 | d2 | x4 | y4 |

I want make VIEW to be like this

| num | did | lat1 | lon1 | lat2 | lon2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d1 | x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 |
| 3 | d2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 |

notice: the condition is compare the 2 rows before and after, by looking at the conditions (same "did"), please help me to code SQL. Thanks

- each row has a "did"
- one "did" allows having "lat" and "lon" values greater than 1
- starting row represents origin
- and next row represents the destination (because they are sequential as far as the "did" is the same) and so on as long as the "did" is the same and if the next row meets the same "did" criteria, then the columns of the second row become columns lat2 and lon2 if the row before and after do not match "did" criteria, it is considered "false"

if in excel like this, because this is only a few rows. But if the number of rows is millions, of course Excel can't reach it, that's why I use a sql database (see screenshots)
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDzTm.jpg)
.

Comment: You'll get more nibbles if you inline the tables with markdown (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) instead of asking people to look at images.

Comment: what exactly is the logic you want? it doesn't make sense how you go from table 1 to table 2

Comment: I want make VIEW from initial table anda result view as explanation above

Comment: Please, describe the logic of conversion and show your current attempt

Comment: Why do you consider x1|y1 a row *before* x2|y2? Rows in a table are unordered, so is there anything that indicates an order and tells us which row to consider first and which row second?

Comment: I suppose x1, y1, etc. are mere placeholders and there are really numbers in the columns? Then 'FALSE' is an inappropriate value, because that's either a boolean or a string, not a number. I suggest you select NULL instead.

Comment: Why do you want this for both MySQL and Oracle? These are different DBMS. Do you have the same database in two different systems? The task would usually be solved with `LEAD`, which is a standard SQL function. MySQL did not support that for a long time, but does now since version 8.

Comment: - each row has a "did"
- one "did" allows having "lat" and "lon" values greater than 1
- starting row represents origin
- and next row represents the destination (because they are sequential as far as the "did" is the same) and so on as long as the "did" is the same and if the next row meets the same "did" criteria, then the columns of the second row become columns lat2 and lon2

if the row before and after do not match "did" criteria, it is considered "false"

Comment: ok, use MySql
skip Oracle

Comment: "starting row represents origin": No. Rows in a table are considered unordered. So if you have two rows for DID d1, one with lat=10 and lon=20 and one with lat=20 and lon=10, then none is the "starting row", none is the "next" row. They are just two rows in the table with no order. Unless you specify an order. Please tell us how to order a DID's rows.

Comment: "use MySql skip Oracle": Okay, I've removed Oracle from your text and from the tags. With MySQL 8 you can adapt Connor McDonald's query. I would remove the `NVL` (that would be `COALESCE` in standard SQL and MySQL), so you get nulls instead of the string 'FALSE'.

Comment: in excel like this, because this is only a few rows. But if the number of rows is millions, of course Excel can't reach it, that's why I use a sql database (see screenshots), thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDzTm.jpg

Comment: In Excel you have row 1, row 2, row 3. In a database table you have row, row, row. So, in Excel you have an inherent order, in a database table you don't. You can add a column to that table that you call rownum or sortkey or whatever, which you can order by. Then your sorting rule for the task may be "sort by sortkey" or "sort by did and inside each did by sortkey". As long as you don't specify an order-by rule, there is no "previous" and "next" row and your task cannot be solved.

Comment: ok I fixed it, according to the instructions. then what for the sql command, please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps ?

```
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3  select 'd1' did, 'x1' lat1, 'y1' lon1 from dual union all
  4  select 'd1' did, 'x2' lat1, 'y2' lon1 from dual union all
  5  select 'd2' did, 'x3' lat1, 'y3' lon1 from dual
  6  ),
  7  t_sequenced as
  8  (
  9  select
 10    t.*,
 11    lead(lat1) over ( partition by did order by lat1 ) as next_lat,
 12    lead(lon1) over ( partition by did order by lat1 ) as next_lon
 13  from t
 14  )
 15  select
 16    did,
 17    lat1,
 18    lon1,
 19    nvl(next_lat,'FALSE') lat1,
 20    nvl(next_lon,'FALSE') lon2
 21  from t_sequenced;

DI LA LO LAT1  LON2
-- -- -- ----- -----
d1 x1 y1 x2    y2
d1 x2 y2 FALSE FALSE
d2 x3 y3 FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: if I use excel it will be like this (screenshot), but because the number of rows is millions, it is impossible for me to use excel. 

this screenshoot........ https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDzTm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following sql to create a view of the requirements and conditions above.In accordance with the instructions of Thorsten Kettner and other contributors above, many thanks.

```
SELECT g1.num, g1.did, g1.LAT1, g1.LON1, g2.lat1 as LAT2, g2.lon1 as LON2
FROM latlon g1 INNER JOIN latlon g2 ON g2.num = ( g1.num + 1 ) 
WHERE g1.DID = g2.DID
```

here's a  [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7Go.jpg)